# How to modify the resolved dependencies of a project in and AfterCompile (or other) task?

Tags: .net, msbuild

How do i modify the resolved dependencies of a project in and AfterCompile (or other) task? Scenario

- project A refs project B
- project B refs project C.

In the [AfterCompile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2022#to-override-a-predefined-target) (or other) of B i want to tweak the transient refs so A does not consume C.